# Error: "Subprocess exited with error 9009" when running cdk

Tags: python, windows, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I've installed the [AWS CDK (Cloud Development Kit)](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/) on Windows 10 and have tried to deploy an existing CDK stack using python on my AWS account.

When running different `cdk` commands, I get the following error message:

```
$ cdk bootstrap
Subprocess exited with error 9009

$ cdk diff
Subprocess exited with error 9009

$ cdk synth
Subprocess exited with error 9009
```

However, running `cdk --version` works:

```
$ cdk --version
2.81.0 (build bd920f2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the CDK app configuration mismatches the Python configuration on Windows.

The `"app"` attribute in the cdk configuration file `./cdk.json` needs to point to the correct python executable.

In my case, I needed to replace:

```
{
  "app": "python3 app.py",
  ...
}
```

with:

```
{
  "app": "python app.py",
  ...
}
```

This is using `python` instead of `python3` which solved my problem. I hope it will solve yours, too.